# Calculating $p$-norms for $f_\epsilon(x)=x^{-1/p+\epsilon}\chi_{(0,a)}(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, normed-spaces

I have some problems calculating this norm, I can't get the integral right. I have the following function $f_{\epsilon}(x)= x^{(-1/p)+\epsilon}\mathcal{X}_{(0,a)}(x)$ with  $p>1$, $a>0$ and $0<\epsilon<1/p$.
Then I have:
\begin{align}
\| \mathcal{H}f_{\epsilon} \|_{p} 
&= \left\| \frac{1}{x} \int_{0}^{x} f_{\epsilon}(t)dt \right\|_{p} \\
&= \left\| \frac{1}{x} \int_{0}^{x} t^{(-1/p)+\epsilon} \mathcal{X}_{(0,a)(t)}dt\right\|_{p}\\ 
&=  \left(\int_{0}^{\infty}\left[\frac{1}{x} \int_{0}^{x} t^{(-1/p)+\epsilon} \mathcal{X}_{(0,a)(t)}dt\right]^{p} dx \right)^{1/p} \\&= \left(\int_{0}^{\infty}\left[\frac{1}{x} \int_{0}^{x} t^{(-1/p)+\epsilon} dt\right]^{p} dx \right)^{1/p} \\& = \left(\int_{0}^{\infty}\left[\frac{1}{x} \frac{p}{\epsilon p -1+p} x^{\frac{\epsilon p -1+p}{p}}  \right]^{p} dx \right)^{1/p} \\& =\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{p}{\epsilon p -1+p} x^{\epsilon p -1}  dx \right)^{1/p} \\& =
\left((\frac{p}{\epsilon p -1+p})^{p}\int_{0}^{\infty}  x^{\epsilon p -1}   dx \right)^{1/p} \\&
 =\frac{p}{\epsilon p -1+p}\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}  x^{\epsilon p -1} dx \right)^{1/p} \\& 
= \frac{p}{\epsilon p -1+p}\left(\int_{0}^{a} x^{\epsilon p -1} dx +\int_{a}^{\infty} x^{\epsilon p -1} dx \right)^{1/p} \\& 
\end{align}

The result should be the following, but I don't know where I have the error.
$$ \| \mathcal{H}f_{\epsilon} \|_{p} = \frac{a^{\epsilon}}{1-\frac{1}{p}+\epsilon} \left(\frac{1}{\epsilon p}+\frac{1}{p-1}\right)^{1/p}$$

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that you can split the outer integration $\int_0^\infty$ as $\int_0^a +\int_a^\infty$. In the first region, $\chi_{(0,a)}(t)=1$ for all $t\in (0,x)$. In the second, the $t$-integral cuts off at $t=a$. These two facts make it tractable to compute $\|\mathcal{H}f_\epsilon\|_p^p$.

Comment: To clarify one aspect of this: The splitting of the outer integration must happen *before* the inner integration is carried out. The point is that the $t$-integral depends on whether $x>a$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I've already done it.

Comment: If you've solved it successfully, I encourage you to submit the result as an answer to your own question. That'll let you accept this as the answer and give us an opportunity to give you rep.